# Kivy module, getting text input

Tags: python, kivy

I'm a newbie with Kivy, and I'm tying to code a simple login system. I've got a problem on getting text from TextInput. This is the code:

```
class MyGrid(Widget):
passw = ObjectProperty(None)

def pressing(self):
    p = self.passw.text
    print("Name: ", p)

class MainWindow(Screen):

    grid = MyGrid()

    def wrong(self):
        show_popup()
```

And from the .kv file I wrote:

```
<MainWindow>:
name: "main"
GridLayout:

    passw:passw

    cols: 1

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        Label:
            text: "Enter password: "
        TextInput:
            id: passw
            multiline: False
    Button:
        text: "Submit"
        on_release:
            root.grid.pressing()
            app.root.current = "second" if passw.text == "something" else root.wrong()
            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
```

The problem is that when I press the button it crashes printing on console:

```
p = self.passw.text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `self.root.ids.passw.text` instead of `self.passw.text`.